# Inner SELECT can't use `u.id` which is in outer SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(b.`id`) AS todayOverdue,
    DATE_FORMAT(t.`created_time`, "%Y%m%d") AS days
FROM
    `Bill` b
LEFT JOIN `Order` o ON b.`order_id` = o.`id`
LEFT JOIN `Trade` t ON o.`trade_id` = t.`id`
LEFT JOIN `User` u ON b.`user_id` = u.`id`
WHERE
b. `deadline` <= "' . $todayTime . '" 
AND b. `deadline` >= "' . $todayDate . '" 
AND b.`is_paid` = 0
AND (
    SELECT
        COUNT(b2.`id`)
    FROM
        `Bill` b2
    WHERE
        b2.`deadline` <= "' . $todayTime . '"
    AND b2.`user_id` = u.`id`
    AND b2.`is_paid` = 0
    OR (
        b2.`deadline` <= b2.`paid_time`
        AND b2.`is_paid` = 1
    )
) < 2
GROUP BY
    days
```

Why can't the inner SELECT use `u.id` which is in outer SELECT?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: It's probably nested too deep

Comment: The u.id which is in outer SELECT is not work,if u.`id` = '10004',inner SELECT this sql: b2.`user_id` = u.`id`  no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner select is completely independent of the outer select. The u table is being joined in the outer select in ways that are unknown to the inner select.

When you have

```
AND b2.`user_id` = u.`id`
```

Which row in u is being compared to which row in b2? The server has no way of knowing, so you need to define a table u2 and join it in the inner select.

Comment: But I want use u.`id` whitch is in outer select in inner select,how can I do please?

Comment: You can't. You need to create a join for User in the inner select.